# Views não carregando express/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

[image]

Criei um pasta camisa dentro da pasta Views, e ao direcionar o arquivo ejs para ser aberto 'marvel.ejs' ele não consegue encontrar. Encontra apenas se eu por o marvel.ejs dentro da pasta Views e em nenhuma subpasta.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O caminho da pagina não está tendo problema, apenas para renderizar o arquivo ejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás a trocas ferramentas que o Express.js te disponibiliza.

O [`app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) espera como primeiro parâmetro o `url` ou uma RegExp para tratar urls. Depois para mostrar a página usas o [`res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) e aí sim, ele espera o caminho para a diretoria onde tens as views.

Assim o teu código deve ser (simplificado):

```
app.use('/meu-url', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/camisa/marvel');
});
```